# Jasmine ignore private function in an Ionic App 1

Tags: angularjs, cordova, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine

I have been searching through the internet for hours but didn't figure out how to fix my issue.

Here is my issue:

I'm unit-testing my controller with some calls to other services but in my controller I have a private function:

```
         function showFileinAppB(pathFile, id) {
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open(pathFile, '', '');

            if (ctrl.isOnline) {
                ....
            } else {
                ApiService.countViewFile(id);
            }
        }
```

I'm stuck right at this line of code since it's calling to the native app cordova. I couldn't inject it to the test.

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(pathFile, '', '');
```

So my question is how to make my test ignore that line of code or is there any better ways to deal with private functions without changing code structure?

Edit: This is how I set up the unit test

```
describe('MyController', function() {
beforeEach(module('IonicApp'));

var $controller,
    $scope,
    $rootScope,
    $q,
    ApiService;

var cordova;

var fake = function() {
    return true;
};

var fakePromise = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve('Result');

    return deferred.promise;
};

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _$q_, _ApiService_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller = _$controller_('MyController', {
        $scope: $scope
    });
    $q = _$q_;
    ApiService = _ApiService_;

    spyOn(ApiService, 'countViewFile').and.callFake(fake);

    cordova = {
        InAppBrowser: {
            open: function(fd, aa, bb) {

            }
        }
    };


}));

it('Should be available', function() {
    expect($controller).toBeDefined();
});

describe('MyController.onViewOnline', function() {
    it('Should be available and call services', function() {
        cordova.InAppBrowser.open = function(fd, aa, bb) {
            return true;
        };

        expect($controller.onViewOnline).toBeDefined();

        $controller.onViewOnline('item');
    });
})
```

})

Comment: Can you post your test code? I'm specifically looking for how you set up your controller to test it.

Comment: Just mock it. In your test, maybe in a `beforeEach` or in the test itself, add code like `cordova.InAppBrowser.open = function (path, something, whatever) {};`. Then the default code won't run...

Comment: - MBielski please check it I just posted it

Comment: Mike McCaughan please have a look. I do as you advised but it's still not working tho

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that and that is not even advised.
And it's not possible to test private functions, one solution is that if that function is being called from any other function then you can test results over there.

Comment: Could you please read my post again. There is some misunderstanding here